# How to Access values from mydata.values() in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

i am selecting data using django Query.Query is

```
 mydata=MyModel.objects.all().values()
  for newmydata in mydata:
        return HttpResponse(newmydata .values())
```

newmydata .values() is printing all my values.its not printing keys.i want to access each values.and also i Want to add some extra values into this (newmydata .values()) array.How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of what you want but here goes:

`MyModel.objects.values()` will return the objects in a dict-like object like so:

```py
[
  {
    'id': 1,
    'first_name': 'Brian',
    'last_name': 'Johnson',
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'first_name': 'Mary',
    'last_name': 'Johnson',
  },
  ...
]
```

If you then take one of the items and do `.values()` on it, you'll get `values` returned like when you are using a `dict`, so you'd get:

`(1, 'Brian', 'Johnson')` for the first iteration of your loop. I imagine you simply want to do:

```py
for newmydata in mydata:
    return HttpResponse(newmydata)
```

You can then add extra data like:

```py
for newmydata in mydata:
    newmydata.update(foo='bar', this='that')
    return HttpResponse(newmydata)
```

Does that make sense?